# Json-c запись в файл

Tags: c

Делаю турнирную таблицу на си и хочу заносить/читать строки с игроками и командами через json. Нашел json-c, но не понял, можно ли делать запись в файл в формате json структур с помощью функций этой библиотеки? Если да то как?

Comment: Вот этот [json-c](https://github.com/json-c/json-c)? Если так, то лучше в тексте вопроса сделайте эту ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там есть такой файл - json_util.h, а в нем есть все, что Вам нужно

```
extern int json_object_to_file(const char *filename, struct json_object *obj);
```

на вход получает имя файла (его Вы знаете) и объект с json объектом (он у Вас наверно то уже есть). Функция возвращает -1, если что то пошло не так.

В этом файле есть много других функций для чтения/сохранения json.